Azure Devops pipeline throwing error while running powershell script - The string is missing the terminator: "
I'm trying to register schedule for Azure automation runbook by using below PS command
Register-AzureRmAutomationScheduledRunbook -AutomationAccountName $automationAccount -ResourceGroupName $automationRg -RunbookName $runBookName -ScheduleName $scheduler.Name -Parameters @{"RESOURCEGROUP"="test-rg";"APPNAME"="test-app-del";"SUBSCRIPTIONID"="test-sub";"BRAND"="MS";"ENV"="dev"} -ErrorAction Stop

The script is executing fine in local machine and able to register schedule for runbook. But when the same code being executed for azure devops pipeline I'm getting below error.
The string is missing the terminator: ".
I tried different suggestions provided to find if there are any special characters in the commandlet. But no luck.

Could you please help in resolving the error
I'm using task: AzureCLI@2 and below is the part code within the task. The issue happens when I add this line of code Register-AzureRmAutomationScheduledRunbook
$automationAccount = $rbEnv+"-aa-ng-infra"
$automationRg=$rbEnv+"-rg-ng-infra-shared"
$webSiteName = "pre${{parameters.brand}}-website-${{parameters.brand}}"
$webSiteRG = $rbEnv+"-rg-ng-pre${{parameters.brand}}-website-eau"
$runBookName = "Retire-Container-App"
# check automation runbook exists
$runbook = Get-AzureRmAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName $automationAccount -Name $runBookName" -ResourceGroupName $automationRg
$TimeZone = "Australia/Sydney"
$startTime = ([System.DateTimeOffset]::Now.AddHours("${{parameters.deleteContainerAppIn}}"))
$scheduler = New-AzureRmAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName $automationAccount -Name "${{parameters.brand}}-aa-sch-eau" -OneTime -ResourceGroupName $automationRg -StartTime $startTime -TimeZone $TimeZone

Register-AzureRmAutomationScheduledRunbook -AutomationAccountName $automationAccount -ResourceGroupName $automationRg -RunbookName $runBookName -ScheduleName $scheduler.Name -Parameters @{'RESOURCEGROUP'='test-rg';'APPNAME'='test-app-del';'SUBSCRIPTIONID'='test-sub';'BRAND'='MS';'ENV'='dev'} -ErrorAction Stop


It would help to see at least the part of the pipeline where this script is executed.

Are you using a PowerShell@2 task in your pipeline? And have you put it on a single line encased in double quotes? If so, just change the double quotes in your PowerShell command above to single quotes. Or you can escape each double quote with a backtick.

Updated the question with the PS Code as well as the task details.

I tried replace "" with '' and also tried escape the double quotes. Still running into same issue.

try hardcode your start time $runbookStartTime = $Date = $([DateTime]::Now.AddMinutes(10))

@Madhu If the script given is same script. In $runbook declaration you are using a single unwanted " in -Name. crosscheck.

As I mentioned in the comment. The error is throwing related to unwanted " in $runbook variable declaration's -Name $runBookName" .
Below is my .yml file for Azure DevOps, which worked for me.
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Powershell script
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Install-Module -Name Az -AllowClobber -Force
      $TenantId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      $ApplicationId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      $clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
      $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ApplicationId, $SecurePassword
      Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential
      $automationAccount = "powshellscript"
      $RgName= "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
      $runBookName = "testscript"
      $runbook = Get-AzureRmAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName $automationAccount -Name $runBookName -ResourceGroupName $RgName
      $TimeZone = "Australia/Sydney"
      $schedule = New-AzAutomationSchedule -AutomationAccountName $automationAccount -Name "Schedule01" -StartTime "23:00Z" -OneTime -ResourceGroupName $RgName -TimeZone $TimeZone
      Register-AzAutomationScheduledRunbook -AutomationAccountName $automationAccount -RunbookName  -ScheduleName $schedule.Name -ResourceGroupName $RgName

OUTPUT:


